# Why didn't anyone in the Galactic Senate raise a motion against the formation of the Empire?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Bail Organa, Padme Amidala and other members of the delegation of 2000. They could have at least argued against it.

Comment: They would have lost.

Comment: Yes, but it's still worth a try, isn't it?

Comment: Nope. Bad idea that'll get you killed.

Comment: @Valorum : they didn't know yet that the Emperor would have gone that far.

Comment: @vsz Valorum's answer indicates otherwise.  That is what tends to happen to 'enemies of the State'.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is addressed in the [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization)). In short, the vote was a done deal and the "2000" were already being systematically rounded up. Bail was in favour of raising a vote against the Empire Act but Padmé argues (successfully) that they should all position themselves as *pro-Empire* by voting for Palpatine, allowing them to remain in positions of power and to work against the Empire from the inside.

> So this is how liberty dies, she was saying to herself. With cheering,
>   and applause.
>
> “We can’t let this happen!” Bail lurched to his feet. “I have to get
>   to my pod-we can still enter a motion-“
>
> “No.” Her hand seized his arm with astonishing strength, and for the
>   first time since he’d arrived, she looked straight into his eyes. **“No,
>   Bail, you can’t enter a motion. You can’t. Fang Zar has already been
>   arrested, and Tundra Dowmeia, and it won’t be long until the entire
>   Delegation of the Two Thousand are declared enemies of the state. You
>   stayed off that list for good reason; don’t add your name by what you
>   do today.”** “But I can’t just stand by and watch-” “You’re right. You
>   can’t just watch. You have to vote for him.”
>
> “What?”
>
> “Bail, it’s the only way. It’s the only hope you have of remaining in
>   a position to do anyone any good. Vote for Palpatine. Vote for the
>   Empire. Make Mon Mothma vote for him, too. Be good little Senators.
>   Mind your manners and keep your heads down. And keep doing … all those
>   things we can’t talk about. All those things I can’t know. Promise me,
>   Bail.”

A similar scene appears in the [Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization)). Again, Bail is in favour of doing *something*. Padmé talks him out of it.

> Bail’s mind began to move at last. He was a Senator; he could speak
>   out against this … abomination. He started to stand, and Padmé put a
>   restraining hand on his arm. He stared at her. “We cannot let this
>   happen!” he said. Surely she agreed with him!
>
> But Padmé shook her head. “Not now!” she said urgently. She glanced
>   toward the podium, and then toward the entrances, and for the first
>   time Bail noticed the red-clad guards and clone troopers standing at
>   attention. They had always been there, it seemed; first, as part of
>   the ceremony and respect due the Senate, and later, during the war, as
>   a security measure to protect the Senators. But just who would they be
>   protecting now?
>
> Feeling cold, Bail relaxed back into his seat. Padmé nodded sadly.
>   “There will be a time,” she said, but she sounded as if it was more of
>   a hope or a dream than a certainty.
>
> Yes. There will be a time, Bail thought. He stared at the figure on
>   the podium, and felt his face harden. He had been devoted to democracy
>   all his life. He would spend the rest of it trying to restore what the
>   Chancellor — no, Emperor, now — had taken away.

Comment: Sounds similar to how many delegates of the German parliament (not only the majority parties) voted to [give law-giving powers to Hitler's government in 1933](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enabling_Act_of_1933).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: I always assumed that was explicitly the inspiration for the storyline.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann And if you want to see what happens if you don't do that, the Czechoslovakian parliament (still in majority even) tried to resist the growing communist power. It "was the right thing to do", but the only result was that it gave the communists all the power they needed right there and then. In the end, if you control the military and the police... you're the government. All those democratic principles work great in a democracy, but are huge vulnerabilities to exploit for people with authoritarian tendencies. By the point it becomes obvious, it's probably too late.

Comment: One of the great missteps that anyone can take is supporting evil with hopes of "opposing from the inside". Of "softening the blow". If you're inside you're part of it. If you're softening the blow, there's still a blow. Doing nothing is the same as taking part. Resist.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica - For all things there is a season.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I'm pretty sure [Oskar Schindler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oskar_Schindler) would disagree

Answer (score 5):

They saw how popular it was for one, and realized it would have accomplished nothing.  Also at this point they had some idea of what Palpatine actually was and everything he did to get this point.  With the Jedi wiped out, they lost their only potential allies of significance.  It would only have been 'worth a try' if they were okay throwing their lives away in doing so.  It made much sense to do what they (minus Padme of course) eventually did, becoming secret leaders of the new rebellion.

Comment: Not just their lives either, possibly. The senate would probably happily allow some sanctions etc. against the sectors they represent too - as we see in the Empire's rule that follows, those can range all the way from discrimination, through slavery and into outright extermination.